# Is there a way to get detailed logs on LUIS classifications?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, direct-line-botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm building chatbots with the Microsoft Bot Framework (and the Composer). To help troubleshoot problems with my bot, or identify issues, it would be helpful if I could see detailed information on LUIS's classification of user intents. I have used other bot frameworks that have a way to see, for example, intent classification confidence. This information would be extremely useful to identify times when the bot is more likely to have screwed up in its responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LUIS API to get predictions from your LUIS APP rather than using the default composer mechanism of getting predictions from LUIS.

1. Make a LUIS API call with your query.
2. LUIS returned the predictions.
3. Store the LUIS response in application insights (or any logging application you are using)
4. Periodically, you can see the logs, which will give you insights into LUIS prediction for each query.